# A user is rolling back a Moderator edit, what more can be done?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer, rude-or-abusive

It's about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33045256/8620333) that I flagged because it contains rude/noisy content. The moderators removed the noise but the OP rollback to a previous version.

I tried to do the same but still, the OP persist in keeping the rude content.

What else could be done to avoid such a rollback war? a lock on the answer?

As a side note, I would delete such answer because it doesn't answer the question and is not useful at all but the community decided otherwise.

<sub>**PS**: I know the moderators are on strike and I encourage them but still we need to raise such issues to show that their work is, indeed, important on the site</sub>

Comment: I also feel there is a good duplicate for the whole question with better answers but couldn't find one actually. If anyone can do it would be good.

Comment: Flag again. It'll be handled eventually. We have systems for repeated rollbacks after warnings

Comment: It should be noted that the OP was also a bit rude with me in the comment section and he confirms that his answer doesn't work --> *My workaround doesn't really work*.

Comment: @Zoeisonstrike ok will do

Comment: The question *as asked* is "Does anyone know why vw/vh include scrollbars as part of the viewport?". This is either opinion-based, or else can only be answered by reference to some documentation of the design decision - which is just plain not useful. (The useful kind of "why" question is one where OP wants to understand mechanically how a result comes about - stuff like Python's object assignment semantics.) The question OP *actually seems to want to ask*, however, is "how do I make the layout do what I want, given that the scrollbars are included?".

Comment: @KarlKnechtel actually the question is how to make "square" elements that fit all the width. I think I will consider this and close the question as duplicate (then vote to delete it) because actually none of the answers are helpful in regard of the scrollbar issue. Only one answer is giving the layout solution (with a very old hacky way)

Comment: I doubt that voting to delete the question is the "right" answer here. After the noise from the answer is (re)removed I don't see why the whole post has to go. 33 people found the question helpful, and 53 that answer. Generally removing helpful content is the wrong path.

Comment: I must admit that the user in question is highly confrontation though, so not further engaging in the comments is the best thing. The strike will mean that it take awhile for the flag(s) to be addressed but it will be. Maybe the user will have a change of "heart" after time. That *8 years* have passed doesn't change that the post isn't "ok"; it was just missed for that long and no one did the right thing and editted/flagged it for 7~ years.

Comment: I don't agree with changing the question to give a different meaning invalidating the existing answer. The answerer quotes that he was answering the "Why" part of the question,  which seems a valid answer to that question. If the question itself is invalid(say "opinion based"), then it should've been closed long before. If it is closed/deleted now, then we should consider whether it adds value or of historical significance regarding CSS decisions, then a historical significance lock is also valid. Also, I don't see which part of OP's response do you consider rude(maybe it was deleted?).

Comment: The author of the answer explicitly calls people "stupid", @TheMaster . You can see what was changed in the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/33045256/revisions), which were the parts that were deemed inappropriate.

Comment: @ThomA  I was referring to Temani's statement in the comments: [*the OP was also a bit rude with me in the comment section*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425340/a-user-is-rolling-back-a-moderator-edit-what-more-can-be-done?noredirect=1#comment963405_425340). I am not sure whether he was rude with OP, as Temani suggests

Comment: @ThomA Regarding rude content in answer, I believe the CoC was different back then. Even so,  since the perceived rudeness isn't directed at specific individuals, but against a group directly involved in decisions, I think it is allowed. For eg, [harmful policy](//stackoverflow.com/conduct/political-speech) says *where pointed or harsh criticism of political figures, their policies, ... can be allowed... and do not contain insulting language directed at individuals.*. [Abusive behavior](//stackoverflow.com/conduct/abusive-behavior) also mentions hostile comments directed against individuals.

Comment: @ThomA there is no helpful content in that Q/A. The only helpful content is the accepted answer that provides an outdated way to solve the issue. I gave a duplicate with better and modern answers

Comment: @TheMaster I didn't change the question meaning and the accepted answer (the only valid answer there) still answer the question as it is now. I simply reworded the title to make more accurate.

Comment: And closing as a dupe is fine, @TemaniAfif , but that doesn't mean you should try to delete the post afterwards.

Comment: @ThomA I have the privilege to vote to delete a closed question so if I think it's not useful I will do it. I don't have a super delete power. 2 other users need to also vote to delete it.

Comment: Delete votes aren't super downvotes, @TemaniAfif ... From [access to moderator tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools): *"Also, be cautious when deleting questions closed as **duplicates**; [they can serve as a signpost](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/20/linking-duplicate-questions/), directing users to useful answers on another question."*

Comment: @ThomA I never said that

Comment: Why is everybody going after this guy and his answer? Seems like he just expressed his frustration about a thing that was relevant then, a frustration shared by many others by the look of all the upvotes. His explanation in the comments that said the post with the bolded content removed was *not his answer* is also deleted. He clearly said delete the post if it's wrong, or keep the post with his bolded text as that is his answer. So why still go after him editing his posts? Seems to be just trying to bait him at this point. Just delete the answer if it's wrong or unhelpful.

Comment: @user13267 Stack Overflow is not forum or a chat. There is no place to express frustration here and call people "stupid". Create a blog to express your frustration and share your thoughts. And upvotes don't make your answer immune to the rules.

Comment: My comment isn't directed to you as you don't have the power to delete that post (you can vote to delete if you want I suppose, that's up to you). Looks like his rude comment to you is deleted so you got what you wanted. The post itself does not call you any names from what I see. His comment about why he needs the bolded text in his answer is also deleted, which is what I pointed out. What I said still stands.

Comment: "I would delete such answer because it doesn't answer the question and is not useful at all **but the community decided otherwise**."  Mh. And this didn't make you consider the problem might be *you*? Interesting.

Comment: @ZJR That's an inappropriate distraction and unnecessarily personal. The fact that there's a chance that one particular curator might have a non-consensual opinion that the answer should be removed altogether does not invalidate the fact that rolling back these edits from a moderator was completely and unquestionably inappropriate.

Comment: @E_net4isonstrike I have more considerations, here, and I don't think my conduct is the one that's inappropriate. TemaniAffif CHANGED THE TITLE of this 8 YEAR OLD question (literally the answer is older than his account, sigh), then, once the question was no longer worth a separate answer, closed it as as duplicate of other questions. My old answer was also made non pertinent to this completely modified answer.

Comment: Questions and answers may be edited or closed _regardless of age_, @ZJR. Age does not make posts immune from curation. The edit to this question in particular had its reasoning (it was made to focus more on what the OP was really hoping to achieve, rather than why an unintended outcome was observed in the code given), but once again, that is not the focus of this Meta question. If you want to argue against the edit to the question, you can take it to a separate question here on Meta SO.

Answer (score 13):

> Flag again. It'll be handled eventually. We have systems for repeated rollbacks after warnings

-- [comment](/q/425340/#comment963404_425340) by [Zoe is on strike](/users/6296561) ♦ Mod

[Yaakov Ellis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51/yaakov-ellis) has since reverted the post as well to the [revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/33045256/revisions) made by a prior moderator.